# Plotly dropdown menu fails to update marker symbol

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I’m working from the data set linked [here](https://github.com/PlatosTwin/LawSchoolData/blob/main/lsdata_cleaned.csv) and trying to produce `plotly` graphs that resemble [these](https://github.com/PlatosTwin/LawSchoolData/blob/main/Graphs/Stanford_timeline.pdf) I’ve made with `matplotlib` (see image below).

The full reproducible code is below.

```
import datetime as dt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

#  Read-in admissions data
filename_admitdata = '/Users/Shared/lsdata_cleaned.csv'
df11 = pd.read_csv(filename_admitdata, low_memory=False)

#  Convert sent_at and decision_at to datetime
df11.loc[:, 'sent_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df11['sent_at'])
df11.loc[:, 'decision_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df11['decision_at'])

cycles = [18, 19, 20, 21]

#  Normalize years
for i, cycle in enumerate(cycles[1:]):
    df11.loc[df11['cycle'] == cycle, 'sent_at'] = \
        df11[df11['cycle'] == cycle]['sent_at'].map(lambda x: dt.datetime(x.year - (i + 1), x.month, x.day))

    df11.loc[df11['cycle'] == cycle, 'decision_at'] = \
        df11[df11['cycle'] == cycle]['decision_at'].map(lambda x: dt.datetime(x.year - (i + 1), x.month, x.day))

top_eleven_list = ['Yale University', 'Harvard University', 'Stanford University', 'University of Chicago',
                   'Columbia University', 'New York University', 'University of Pennsylvania', 'University of Virginia',
                   'University of Michigan', 'University of California—Berkeley', 'Northwestern University']

fig = go.Figure()

#  Add traces
for c in cycles:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df11[(df11['school_name'] == 'Yale University') & (df11['cycle'] == c)]['sent_at'],
        y=df11[(df11['school_name'] == 'Yale University') & (df11['cycle'] == c)]['decision_at'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(
            size=6,
            color=df11[(df11['school_name'] == 'Yale University') & (df11['cycle'] == c)]['color'],
            symbol=df11[(df11['school_name'] == 'Yale University') & (df11['cycle'] == c)]['marker'],
            line=dict(
                width=1,
                color=df11[(df11['school_name'] == 'Yale University') & (df11['cycle'] == c)]['splits'])),
        name=str(c-1) + '/' + str(c),
        type='scatter',
        text=df11['cycle'],
        hovertemplate='Cycle: 20%{text}<br>' + 'Sent: %{x}<br>' + 'Decision: %{y}<extra></extra>'
        )
    )

#  Dropdown menu
updatemenu = []
buttons = []

#  Button with one option for each school
for school in top_eleven_list:
    buttons.append(
        dict(
            method='update',
            label=school,
            visible=True,
            args=[{
                'x': [df11[(df11['school_name'] == school) & (df11['cycle'] == c)]['sent_at'] for c in cycles],
                'y': [df11[(df11['school_name'] == school) & (df11['cycle'] == c)]['decision_at'] for c in cycles],
                'marker':
                    dict(
                        size=5,
                        color=list(itertools.chain(*[df11[(df11['school_name'] == school) & (df11['cycle'] == c)]['color'] for c in cycles])),
                        symbol=list(itertools.chain(*[df11[(df11['school_name'] == school) & (df11['cycle'] == c)]['marker'] for c in cycles])),
                        line=dict(
                            width=1,
                            color=list(itertools.chain(*[df11[(df11['school_name'] == school) & (df11['cycle'] == c)]['splits'] for c in cycles])))),
                'name': [str(c-1) + '/' + str(c) for c in cycles],
                   },
                  ],
            )
        )

#  Adjust updatemenus
updatemenu = []
menu = dict()
updatemenu.append(menu)

updatemenu[0]['buttons'] = buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction'] = 'down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive'] = True
updatemenu[0]['pad'] = {"r": 10, "t": 10}
updatemenu[0]['x'] = 0.0
updatemenu[0]['xanchor'] = 'left'
updatemenu[0]['y'] = 1.1
updatemenu[0]['yanchor'] = 'top'

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=updatemenu,
    xaxis_title="Sent Date",
    yaxis_title="Decision Date",
    legend_title="App. Cycle"
)

fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="M1",
    tickformat="%B",
    ticklabelmode="period",
    range=[min(df11['sent_at']) - dt.timedelta(days=4), dt.datetime(2018, 3, 15)]
)

fig.update_yaxes(
    dtick="M1",
    tickformat="%B",
    ticklabelmode="period",
    range=[min(df11['decision_at']) - dt.timedelta(days=7), dt.datetime(2018, 5, 7)]
)

fig.show()
```

I have the following questions/troubles:

- When I select a (new) school from the dropdown, the marker symbols seem to scrambled and in the legend they all change to be the same one. (See images below.) I first tried with the marker list nested but that didn't work either. The trouble, I think, is in the dropdown menu section.
- Can the legend marker color be modified, to be gray/neutral rather
  than (randomly) as from plot marker colors?
- Can the sent_at and decision_at hover labels be more specific than
  just months? “03/12” rather than “March”?

Original:

[image: Original]

After selecting Stanford from the dropdown:

[image: After selecting Stanford from the dropdown:]

From `matplotlib`:

[image: From matplotlib]

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the first issue found! I was passing a list of lists within the marker attributes rather than a list of markers. The snippet below does the trick:

```
'marker':
    [dict(
         size=5,
         color=df11[(df11['school_name'] == school) & (df11['cycle'] == c)]['color'],
         symbol=df11[(df11['school_name'] == school) & (df11['cycle'] == c)]['marker'],
         line=dict(
               width=1,
               color=df11[(df11['school_name'] == school) & (df11['cycle'] == c)]['splits'])) for c in cycles],
```

Unresolved: hover labels and legend markers questions. (On the question of customizing legend markers, I came across [this discussion](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3735) for plotly.js.)